# Адрес начала массива

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Есть массив данных, адрес начала этого массива, необходимо записать в память. С первого взгляда, задача тривиальная, но на практике оказалось гораздо сложнее...

```
BYTE ST_1[] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66 };

VOID WINAPI WriteAddr()
{
     BYTE *rData = nullptr;

     rData = (BYTE*)malloc(0x90);

     if(rData)
     {
          ZeroMemory(rData, 0x90);

          memcpy(rData, &ST_1[0], sizeof(BYTE*));

          free(rData);
     }
}
```

Почему-то программа, записывает первые 4 байта массива, но, никак не адрес начала массива в памяти. Получилось, тоже самое, если бы я написал

```
memcpy(rData, ST_1, sizeof(BYTE*));
```

Чуть-чуть поигрался и у меня получилось, то, чего я хотел, но, чего-то я не понимаю

```
BYTE ST_1[] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66 };

VOID WINAPI WriteAddr()
{
     BYTE *rData = nullptr, *pM = nullptr;

     rData = (BYTE*)malloc(0x90);

     if(rData)
     {
          ZeroMemory(rData, 0x90);

          pM = &ST_1[0];

          memcpy(rData, &pM, sizeof(BYTE*));

          free(rData);
     }
}
```

Причем здесь указатель на pM? В переменную pM мы поместили, только адрес начала массива, но сама переменная находиться, совершенно по другому адресу...

Comment: Мой совет вам, не используйте сишное распределение памяти в языке С++, все будет проще и наглядней

Comment: @perfect, странный совет. C++/C программер, если навсегда не хочет остаться среди "кроликов, не приспособленных для лазания", должен в совершенстве освоить работу с памятью.

Comment: @avp а чем плох new и delete?

Comment: @perfect, в рамках канонического C++, конечно, надо использовать new/delete, но во-первых, вопрос по С, а во-вторых, malloc позволяет делать realloc, а в крестах аналога нет.

Comment: оказывается мы спорим не о чем. автор вопроса метки поменял )

Answer (score 4):

Функция `memcpy`, объявленная как

```
void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);
```

копирует `n` символов, адресуемых указателем `s2`, в область памяти, адресуемой указателем `s1`.

Дело в том, что массив - это именованная область памяти.  Поэтому выражения

`&ST_1[0]`, `ST_1` и `&ST_1`  имеют одно и то же значение, которое является адресом первого элемента массива и, соответственно, адресом этой именованной  области. Поэтому если эти выражения использовать в `memcpy`, как, например,

```
memcpy(rData, &ST_1[0], sizeof(BYTE*));
memcpy(rData, ST_1, sizeof(BYTE*));
memcpy(rData, &ST_1, sizeof(BYTE*));
```

то так как значения этих выражений равны, то это значение будет рассматриваться функцией как адрес области, откуда надо скопировать данные. Поэтому всегда будут копироваться элементы массива, расположенные в этой области.

Вам сначала надо занести адрес массива в какую-то промежуточную переменную (область памяти, где будет храниться этот адрес, и откуда вы будете его копировать), а затем значение из этой переменной (области памяти) с помощью указателя на эту переменную (область памяти) копировать, используя `memcpy`, что вы и сделали во втором фрагменте кода

```
pM = &ST_1[0];

memcpy(rData, &pM, sizeof(BYTE*));
```

Comment: "то вы можете записать `memcpy(rData, &ST_1, sizeof(BYTE*));`" - только работать, кажется, не будет. Эта конструкция эквивалентна первый за счёт того, что массив статический. Остальное верно.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Что работать не будет?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow memcpy(rData, &ST_1, sizeof(BYTE*)); - не запишет в rData адрес массива ST_1, а запишет первые его элементы.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Допустил ошибку. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @@Владимир Мартьянов Это бывает, когда думаешь об одном, а пишешь о другом.:)

Comment: @VladD, нет. Он хочет не данные из массива, а адрес. Так что эта часть верна.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Угу, я уже понял.

Answer (score 3):

memcpy читает байты из указанного вами адреса. Вы указали адрес начала массива - оттуда и прочитано N байт. Чтобы memcpy прочитала нужный вам адрес начала его нужно куда-то поместить.
А вообще void* ptr = &ST_1;

Comment: Только не `void* ptr = &ST_1;`, а `void* ptr = ST_1;`.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну может быть, я в тонкостях не силен. Работает и так и этак, то есть заносит в ptr адрес начала массива.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> sizeof(BYTE*)
> ```

Это размер указателя - 4 или 8 байт. Иногда 2.

Надо передавать размер массива самому, sizeof работает только для массивов со статическим размером.

---

Понял. Надо было адрес копировать, а не первый элемент. Тогда так:

```
BYTE *temp = ST_1;
memcpy(rData, &temp, sizeof(temp));
```

Comment: Он хочет адрес массива скопировать, а не сам массив

Comment: @Cerbo, сейчас подумаю.

Comment: @Aviator93, ответ обновлён.

Comment: memcpy тут, в общем-то, не нужен. Делается обычным присывиванием.

Comment: @Cerbo, поправил.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не совсем. Для присваивания понадобится каст к указателю на другой тип, что во-первых, при определённых условиях приводит к UB, а во-вторых, на некоторых архитектурах можно словить UB просто за нарушение выравнивания - массив, в который ведётся запись байтовый и может быть не выровнен по 4 или 8 байтам.

Comment: @Qwertiy:
unsigned char ST_1[] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66 };
unsigned char* foo;
foo = &ST_1[0];
Работает как ожидается.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не понял, что ты пытаешься показать этим примером. Ты утверждаешь, что адреса `ST_1` и `&ST_1` одинаковые или разные? Я считаю, что 1. они одинаковые. 2. даже если они разные, брать адрес не нужно, нужен именно адрес начального элемента.

Comment: @Qwertiy я пытаюсь показать рабочий код с приведением указателя к другому типу, который работает как надо. Адрес начального элемента массива должен быть адресом начала массива, разве нет?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в данном случае, насколько я представляю, да. Но вообще, не всегда.

Comment: @Qwertiy за общие случаи, когда такое работать не будет не скажу - не сталкивался и сходу не могу придумать :-(

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, на хабре была статья с перебором случаев.

Answer (score 1):

```
memcpy(rData, &ST_1[0], sizeof(BYTE*));
```

Не работает как надо, потому что `ST_1[0]` это содержимое первого элемента массива, `&ST_1[0]` — это указатель на первый элемент массива, ровно как и `&ST_1`.
`memcpy` требует на вход указатель на данные, которые будут скопированы. В данном случае Вы подаете указатель на данные массива, поэтому копируется массив (4 байта).

```
pM = &ST_1[0];
memcpy(rData, &pM, sizeof(BYTE*));
```

Работает как надо, поскольку `pm` содержит указатель на первый элемент массива а не содержимое элемента. 
В этом же случае memcpy получает на вход указатель на указатель (`&pm`) и в итоге копирует содержимое указателя `pm`.

А вообще не понятно почему бы просто не сделать `*rData = ST_1`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(BYTE*)
```

дает размер указателя (byte*). На 32 битных системах он равен 4 байтам. memcpy потому и копирует 4 байта, потому что больше не просили. Правильно будет вот так:

memcpy(куда, откуда,sizeof(byte*)*(число элементов массива))

Сам же адрес начала массива в памяти - &ST_1[0], отсюда он и начинается

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно разместить в указанной памяти какой-то адрес?

Нет ничего проще (конечно, если в указанной памяти выделено достаточно для `sizeof(void *)` (это размер указателя) места) и `memcpy()` абсолютно не нужна для такой задачи.

```
static inline char *put_addr (char *dst, void *addr) {
  if (dst)
    *(void **)dst = addr;
  return dst;
}
```

Просто играемся приведением типов и пишем наш адрес в нужное место *простым присваиванием* (обратите внимание, на самом деле (при оптимизирующей компиляции) тут *нет никаких вызовов функций*).

Пример использования (в чем-то похож на Ваш (даже с malloc того же размера, что и исходный массив, адрес которого надо занести в память))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char a[] = "abcdefghijklmn";

  char *x = (typeof(x))put_addr((char *)malloc(sizeof(a)), a);
  if (!x)
    err(EX_OSERR, "put_addr(malloc(), ...)");

  printf("source addr: %p addr in malloc: %p\n", 
         a, *(void **)x);
  memcpy(x, a, sizeof(a));
  put_addr(x, a);
  printf("again with source copy: %p %p [%s]\n", 
         a, *(void **)x, x + sizeof(void *));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем (32-bit linux)

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ c1.c && ./a.out 
source addr: 0xbfa84e0d addr in malloc: 0xbfa84e0d
again with source copy: 0xbfa84e0d 0xbfa84e0d [efghijklmn]
End
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ g++ -S -O c1.c && grep put_data c1.s
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Как  видите, оптимизатор действительно выбрасывает вызов `put_data()`.

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

---

Пожалуй, надо добавить несколько слов о [выравнивании данных в памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) ([alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment), здесь подробнее (но по английски)).

Приведенный выше код `put_addr()` будет без проблем работать на x-86 (наиболее распространен), а вот на большинстве других архитектур (ARM (большинство планшетов и смартфонов), Sparc, Power ...) будет "падать" с segmentation fault в случае, если переданный адрес `dst` не выровнян на естественную для указателя границу (4 для 32-bit, 8 для 64-bit машин). Более переносимый вариант на gcc/g++ может выглядеть  так

```
static char *put_addr (char *dst, void *addr) {
  if (dst)
#ifdef NEED_ALIGNMENT
  #ifdef USE_MEMCPY
    memcpy(dst, &addr, sizeof(void *));
  #else
    {
      struct { void *v __attribute__((packed)); } *s = (typeof(s))dst;
      s->v = addr;
    }
  #endif
#else
    *(void **)dst = addr;
#endif
  return dst;
}
```

Определение переменных времени компиляции `NEED_ALIGNMENT` и `USE_MEMCPY` как обычно ложится на плечи программиста (ну, вычисление NEED_ALIGNMENT можно и автоматизировать, базируясь на выводе `gcc -dM -E - </dev/null`).

Сразу хочу отметить, что компиляция

```
gсс  c1.c -DNEED_ALIGNMENT -DUSE_MEMCPY
```

в нашем случае не приводит к вызову `memcpy()`, поскольку компилятор "знает", что для архитектуры x-86 выравнивание не важно и поэтому непосредственно (инструкция movl) копирует 4 байта адреса.

Comment: Круто, не знал, что оптимизатор знает семантику `memcpy`.

Comment: @VladD, я тоже, пока в процессе ответа не grep-нул `nm a.out` (думал, что ошибся в написании ALIGNMENT), проверил (добавляя puts) и в очередной раз убедился в крутости RMS и его последователей. (а вот, нужны ли тут кому-то такие исследования -- не уверен)

Comment: Ну, мне интересно, и надеюсь, ещё кому-то.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, вы не можете получить адрес переменной массива, созданного на стеке, потому что ее не существует в памяти. Вы правильно создали временную переменную.

Может как-то так (чтобы не создавать временную переменную):

```
template<class T> class rvalue_ptr_base {
public:
    operator T*() const{
        return ptr;
    }
    protected:
    T* ptr;
};

template<class T> class rvalue_ptr : public rvalue_ptr_base<T>{
public:
    rvalue_ptr(T&& t) : 
        data(std::move(t))
        {
            ptr = &data;
        }
protected:
    T data;
};
template<class T> class rvalue_ptr<T[]> : public rvalue_ptr_base<T*>{
public:
    rvalue_ptr(T* t) {
        data = t;
        ptr = &data;
    }
protected:
    T* data;
};

// ...
memcpy(rData, rvalue_ptr<BYTE[]>(ST_1), sizeof(BYTE*));
```

Answer (score -1):

Из заголовка функции `void *memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)` видно, что вторым агрументом является адрес, а в описании функции `memcpy` сказано:

> Функция копирует n байт из области памяти, на которую указывает src, в
>   область памяти, на которую указывает dst. Функция возвращает адрес
>   назначения dst.

Для того, чтобы адрес массива был записан в указанную область памяти, адрес массива вначале нужно поместить к примеру в переменную, а потом адрес этой переменной передать в `memcpy` вторым аргументом.

```
BYTE ST_1[] = { 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66 };

VOID WINAPI WriteAddr()
{
  BYTE *rData = nullptr;
  BYTE* pM = nullptr;
  rData = (BYTE*)malloc(0x90);

  if(rData)
  {
       ZeroMemory(rData, 0x90);

       pM = ST_1;

       memcpy(rData, &pM, sizeof(BYTE));

       free(rData);
  }
}
```

Comment: `pM = (BYTE)ST_1;` - жесть. Неверно.

Comment: @Hunter Killer `BYTE pM = 0;` У Вас размерность адреса получилась один байт

Comment: На скорую руку пробовал то же самое и использовал unsigned int, прошу прощения за нелепость, вариант с указателем на указатель все же лучше.

Answer (score -2):

Приблизительно вот так:

```
memcpy(rData, &ST_1, sizeof(BYTE*));
```

Comment: Скорее всего, как-то не так...

Comment: И оно будет ровно так же копировать 4 байта содержимого массива.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в одном месте ты утверждаешь, что адреса разные, а в другом, что одинаковые?

Comment: @Qwertiy Я утверждаю что приведенный код будет копировать 4 байта содержимого массива. Потому что это memcpy. А вот void* ptr = &ST_1; будет работать как ожидает ТС, потому что мы просто заносим адрес в переменную.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, 99%, что адрес брать не нужно. И 99%, что в данном случае оно на работоспособности не скажется.

Comment: @Qwertiy может адрес в итоге брать и не нужно, но вопрос стоит именно в том, чтобы получить адрес начала массива :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, адрес **начала массива**, а не **адрес указателя на массив, если бы он был**. Т. е. взятие адреса не требуется.

Comment: @Qwertiy посмотрите в отладчике, приведенный мною код получает именно адрес начала массива. Адрес указателя я даже не пытаюсь получить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да. Но только за счёт того, что они равны.